# Should I dismiss DialogFragment in DialogFragment itself (before callback method) or in Activity (in callback method)?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a simple `DialogFragment` with some data and one *button*.

```
public class SimpleDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static interface Callbacks {
        void onButtonClicked(SimpleDialogFragment dialogFragment);
    }

    static SimpleDialogFragment newInstance() {
        return new SimpleDialogFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_simple, null);
        contentView.findViewById(R.id.some_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onSomeButtonClicked();
            }
        })
        return contentView;
    }

    private void onSomeButtonClicked() {
        Callbacks callbacks = (Callbacks) getActivity();
        // 
        // Should I dismiss here?
        // dismiss();
        // 
        callbacks.onSomeButtonClicked(this);
    }

}



public class SimpleActivity extends Activity implements SimpleDialogFragment.Callbacks {

    @Override
    public void onSomeButtonClicked(SimpleDialogFragment dialogFragment) {
        // 
        // Or should I dismiss here?
        // dialogFragment.dismiss();
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling it in `onSomeButtonClicked()` will be fine, just after `callbacks.onSomeButtonClicked(this);`

```
private void onSomeButtonClicked() { 
    Callbacks callbacks = (Callbacks) getActivity();

    callbacks.onSomeButtonClicked(this);
    dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain - *why* in `DialogFragment` and *why* after calling the callback method?

Comment: When you call dismiss() you're popping the object on the backstack and a transaction will begin to remove the dialog. So you want to execute your callBack before this happens.